# How to setup Membership provider in MVC "

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider, membership, simplemembership

I have not used Membership provide even in ASP.NET traditional.

Now, In MVC 4 application, as per design requirement, I need to use Membership provide while login.

Can any one provide me steps or some link guidance to setup Membership in MVC application.

and some basic idea/concepts will be also helpful.

Please guide me.

I am using - ASP.NET MVC 4 - Basic project template.

When try to create internet template and use it then, unable to find database in sql server.... not sure where the database is created. when i change server to point exact my (local) database then, it through initilization error.

please guide , how can i check - what are the exact steps to configure memberhsip ?

Comment: This will help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324544/how-to-add-asp-net-membership-provider-in-a-empty-mvc-4-project-template

Comment: I suggest you follow one of numerous tutorial out there on SMP. One is http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/689801/Understanding-and-Using-Simple-Membership-Provider. After you follow it step by step, if you encounter any issue, share exact problem with more information i.e. web.config entry.

Answer (score -2):

[1](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-7) and watch here [2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/689801/Understanding-and-Using-Simple-Membership-Provider)  ... Second is ASP.NET MVC 4.0

Comment: Please include all relevant information from the links in the answer. Try to keep this a Question and Answer site, not a question and pointer site.