# Login and session management in Asp.net Mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to create a application in which different users have login functionality such as admin, coach and student. Each has there own tasks. So here I want session handling and I am new in asp.net mvc.

Comment: Please refer [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324544/how-to-add-asp-net-membership-provider-in-a-empty-mvc-4-project-template)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Example. Say we want to manage session after checking user validation, so for this demo only I am hard coding checking valid user. On account Login

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
        {
            if(model.UserName=="xyz" && model.Password=="xyz")
            {
                Session["uname"] = model.UserName;
                Session.Timeout = 10;
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
}
```

On Index Page

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if(Session["uname"]==null)
            {
                return Redirect("~/Account/Login");
            }
            else
            {
                return Content("Welcome " + Session["uname"]);
            }
        }
```

On SignOut Button

```
Session.Remove("uname");
return Redirect("~/Account/Login");
```