# How to override the membership provider in ASP.NET MVC 4 in ClassLibrary?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Use in the application pattern "Repository". To create a separate class library, describe methods through interfaces. Decided to override the membership provider. In the library through References to add references to System.Web, create a class in it connect System.Web.Security, and I try to inherit from the abstract class MembershipProvider ... just says that this class does not exist as such, and many other MembershipUser ...

Comment: Yes. I can not to override the Membership Provider in classlibrary,as classlibrary doesn't see class MembershipProvider :(  Why???? Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

no worries about your english, it just needed clarification.

If you have not solved this yet try what is in this post: [How to add ASP.NET Membership Provider in a Empty MVC 4 Project Template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324544/how-to-add-asp-net-membership-provider-in-a-empty-mvc-4-project-template)

It should add the correct references for you.