# Use ASP.Net Membership Provider in MVC (instead of SimpleMembership)

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, sqlmembershipprovider

I have already implemented an MVC4 project using SimpleMembership.

However for certain reasons, i need to integrate the older ASP.NET Membership provider in  the project to replace the SimpleMembership provider.

Is this possible? If so, how can it be done and how would it impact my existing project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add ASP.NET Membership Provider in a Empty MVC 4 Project Template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13324544/how-to-add-asp-net-membership-provider-in-a-empty-mvc-4-project-template)

Comment: .. but it does contain instructions on how to install the ASP.NET Membership provider in a MVC4 project.